# Setting individual polygons to visible/non visible

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get checkboxes to set polygons to visible/non visible on a map. As per the code below it does not work. I presume because the variable type I am passing is incorrect/needs to be cast. But I'm not sure...

How can I write this code so that the area/polygon associated with the checkbox (of the same name) has its visibility toggled?

To be honest I'm new to Javascript and I'm sure I've missing something easy but any help would be appreciated!

```
<script>
var cheyChumneahCoords = [
new google.maps.LatLng(11.567148,104.931901),
new google.maps.LatLng(11.564994,104.925757),
new google.maps.LatLng(11.559585,104.927309),
new google.maps.LatLng(11.562065,104.933274),
new google.maps.LatLng(11.562276,104.935892),
new google.maps.LatLng(11.562234,104.935935),
new google.maps.LatLng(11.562108,104.935977)
];

// Chey Chumneah area
var cheyChumneahArea=new google.maps.Polygon({
  path:cheyChumneahCoords,
  strokeColor:"#0000FF",
  strokeOpacity:0.8,
  strokeWeight:0,
  fillColor:"#0000FF",
  fillOpacity:0.4
  });

function areaChange(areaName, checked)
{
alert("Area " + areaName + " changed and is checked: " + checked); //Debug
cheyChumneahArea.setVisible(checked); //Works
areaName.setVisible(checked); //Does not work
}

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(11.562276,104.919434),
  zoom:14,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap")
  ,mapProp);

cheyChumneahArea.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap"></div>

<div id="areaSelection">
<input type="checkbox" name="areas" value=cheyChumneahArea onchange="areaChange(this.value, this.checked)">Chey Chumneah<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="areas" value="BKK1Area" onchange="areaChange(this.value, this.checked)">BKK1
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

areaName is a string, not an object.

Use the subscript-notation:

```
window[areaName].setVisible(checked);
```